# jquery datatables with thymleaf and <style> tag issue

Tags: css, spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf

My issue is I have a jquery datatables in my page which belongs to a web app using springboot 2.3.2.RELEASE and Java 11 and Thymleaf.

In order to have the same behaviour as the following  : [Jquery datatables Row details](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

I have my png files as follows :

[image: Project directory structure]

and in my Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping createRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        // default message source
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource defaultMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        defaultMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        defaultMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        defaultMessageSource.setCacheSeconds(5000);

        return defaultMessageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("fr"));
        resolver.setCookieName("localeCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(5000);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver result = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        result.setPrefix("/templates/");
        result.setSuffix(".html");
        result.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        result.setOrder(1);
        result.setCacheable(true);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        // templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {

    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

In developer console I have 404 on the link http://localhost:8080/tsp/details_open.png

I'm struggling in vain. Unless I'm mistaken, It's related to static resources handling.

The tsp is coming from the following application.yml file :

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /tsp
```

I have made a seperate test projet, isolated the issue which was my MvcConfig

Any help please ?

Comment: Any idea where the `tsp` comes from in that http://localhost:8080/tsp/details_open.png URL?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe thank you for your question. I have added the explanation in my question :) Please feel free to check.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by updating the MvcConfig class as follows :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

...
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/img/**",
                "/webfonts/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/static/img/",
                        "classpath:/static/webfonts/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver result = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        result.setPrefix("/templates/");
        result.setSuffix(".html");
        result.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        result.setOrder(1);
        result.setCacheable(false);
        return result;
    }
...
}
```

Which means, I changed `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` by `WebMvcConfigurer` and delete useless custom code.

What is weired is that, according to spring documentation, static folder should be automatically loaded...but it's not...this is why I added the resouce handlers.

To optimize, the performance, I copied all js/css/map files locally.